# How to add bits in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, integer, bit-manipulation, bit

Say you have two integers 10 and 20. That is `00001010` and `00010100`. I would then like to just basically concat these as strings, but have the result be a new integer.

```
00001010 + 00010100 == 0000101000010100
```

That final number is `2580`.

However, I am looking for a way to do this without actually converting them to string. Looking for something more efficient that just does some bit twiddling on the integers themselves. I'm not too familiar with that, but I imagine it would be along the lines of:

```
var a = 00001010 // == 10
var b = 00010100 // == 20
var c = a << b //   == 2580
```

Note, I would like for this to work with any sequences of bits. So even:

```
var a = 010101
var b = 01110
var c = a + b == 01010101110
```

Comment: `a + (b << 8)` is likely what you are looking for, or use typed arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basic equation is:

```
c = b + (a << 8).
```

The trick here is that you need to always shift by 8. But since `a` and `b` do not always use all 8 bits in the byte, JavaScript will automatically omit any leading zeros. We need to recover the number of leading zeros (of `b`), or trailing zeros of `a`, and prepend them back before adding. This way, all the bits stay in their proper position. This requires an equation like this:

```
c = b + (a << s + r)
```

Where `s` is the highest set bit (going from right to left) in `b`, and `r` is the remaining number of bits such that `s + r = 8`.

Essentially, all you are doing is shifting the first operand `a` over by 8 bits, to effectively add trailing zeros to `a` or equally speaking, padding leading zeros to the second operand `b`. Then you add normally. This can be accomplishing using logarithms, and shifting, and bitwise `OR` operation to provide an `O(1)` solution for some arbitrary **positive integers** `a` and `b` where the number of bits in `a` and `b` do not exceed some positive integer `n`. In the case of a byte, `n = 8`.

```
// Bitwise log base 2 in O(1) time
function log2(n) {

  // Check if n > 0

  let bits = 0;

  if (n > 0xffff) {
      n >>= 16;
      bits = 0x10;
  }

  if (n > 0xff) {
      n >>= 8;
      bits |= 0x8;
  }

  if (n > 0xf) {
      n >>= 4;
      bits |= 0x4;
  }

  if (n > 0x3) {
      n >>= 2;
      bits |= 0x2;
  }

  if (n > 0x1) {
      bits |= 0x1;
  }

  return bits;
}

// Computes the max set bit
// counting from the right to left starting
// at 0. For 20 (10100) we get bit # 4.
function msb(n) {

  n |= n >> 1;
  n |= n >> 2;
  n |= n >> 4;
  n |= n >> 8;
  n |= n >> 16;

  n = n + 1;

  // We take the log here because
  // n would otherwise be the largest
  // magnitude of base 2. So, for 20,
  // n+1 would be 16. Which, to 
  // find the number of bits to shift, we must 
  // take the log base 2
  return log2(n >> 1);
}

// Operands
let a = 0b00001010  // 10
let b = 0b00010100  // 20

// Max number of bits in
// in binary number
let n = 8

// Max set bit is the 16 bit, which is in position
// 4. We will need to pad 4 more zeros
let s = msb(b) 

// How many zeros to pad on the left
// 8 - 4 = 4
let r = Math.abs(n - s)

// Shift a over by the computed 
// number of bits including padded zeros
let c = b + (a << s + r)

console.log(c)
```

Output:

```
2580
```

Notes:

- This is NOT commutative.
- Add error checking to log2() for negative numbers, and other edge cases.

References:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-significant-set-bit-number/
- https://github.com/N02870941/java_data_structures/blob/master/src/main/java/util/misc/Mathematics.java

Comment: i like how your references have nothing to do with javascript. this is all you need to explain it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @GottZ They are code references that provide intuition as to how I came up with a potential language agnostic solution the original post, which I find more valuable than a specification on JavaScript bitwise operations. I think the original poster understands bitwise operation / arithmetic. The roadblock is USING it to come up with an efficient solution to a particular problem. Also, the link you posted uses `parseInt()` to convert a String object to binary. The requirement of the original post says he strictly would like to avoid using strings. Thank you for your concern though!

Answer (score 2):

so the problem:
a is 10 (in binary 0000 1010)
b is 20 (in binary 0100 0100)
you want to get 2580 using bit shift somehow.

if you right shift a by 8 using a<<=8 (this is the same as multiplying a by 2^8) you get 
1010 0000 0000 which is the same as 10*2^8 = 2560.
 since the lower bits of a are all 0's (when you use << it fills the new bits with 0) you can just add b on top of it 1010 0000 0000 + 0100 0100 gives you 1010 0001 0100.
so in 1 line of code, it's `var result = a<<8 + b`. 
 Remember in programming languages, most of them have no explicit built-in types for "binary". But everything is binary in its nature. so int is a "binary", an object is "binary" ....etc. When you want to do some binary operations on some data you can just use the datatype you have as operands for binary operations. 
this is a more general version of how to concatenate two numbers' binary representations using no string operations and data

```js
/*
  
  This function concate b to the end of a and put 0's in between them.  
  
  b will be treated starting with it's first 1 as its most significant bit
  
  b needs to be bigger than 0, otherwise, Math.log2 will give -Infinity for 0 and NaN for negative b
  
  padding is the number of 0's to add at the end of a
*/

function concate_bits(a, b, padding) {

  //add the padding 0's to a
  a <<= padding;

  //this gets the largest power of 2
  var power_of_2 = Math.floor(Math.log2(b));
  var power_of_2_value;

  while (power_of_2 >= 0) {
    power_of_2_value = 2 ** power_of_2;
    a <<= 1;
    if (b >= power_of_2_value) {
      a += 1;
      b -= power_of_2_value;
    }
    power_of_2--;
  }
  return a;
}

//this will print 2580 as the result
let result = concate_bits(10, 20, 3);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note, I would like for this to work with any sequences of bits. So even:

```
var a = 010101
var b = 01110
var c = a + b == 01010101110
```

This isn't going to be possible unless you convert to a string or otherwise store the number of bits in each number.  `10101` `010101` `0010101` etc are all the same number (21), and once this is converted to a number, there is no way to tell how many leading zeroes the number originally had.